# Manipulating input checkbox

Tags: jquery

`input type="checkbox"` will not uncheck or checked not unless if confirmed on dialog confirmation box.

Here is the scenario, i have this table contained with records each row of record has an `Enabled` column which will allow you to `checked` or `unchecked` a specific row record means(Disable or enable an account record).

My problem is, when i click the `[input type="checkbox"]` it will auto check or sometimes when it is checked by default it will auto unchecked then the dialog appears for confirmation for enabling or disabling an account.

I want the checkbox to do nothing when i clicked it. It should only change after i confirm it on dialog box.

Hi guys, sorry this us my code anyway. http://jsfiddle.net/5REXp/1/
I hope you understand it. A Jquery UI dialog should popup when you click the checkbox un column named enabled. Thanks.

Comment: please share your html and the script you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="Enabled(201569,event, this)" />
```

and

```
<div id="dialog-confirm">Confirm</div>
```

then

```
function Enabled(id, event, el) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 160,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Disable": function () {
                $(this).dialog('option', 'hide', 'fade');
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $(el).prop('checked', !$(el).is(':checked'))
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(this).dialog("destroy");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4EU95/)

Comment: This is a some sort of spoon feeding. :D, through stackoverflow we don't care what nationalities or what type of people are here. In here i feel we are united as one. Drama. haha. It is all about knowledge! Magnificent work arun this is the second time you helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this code. I think this is what you want:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" class="chkb"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2" class="chkb"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk3" class="chkb"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.chkb').click(function(){
        var Status=$(this).is(':checked');
        if(Status==true)
        {
            $(this).attr('checked',false);
            var conf=confirm('Mark It?');
            if(conf==true)
                $(this).prop('checked',true);
            else
                $(this).prop('checked',false);
        }
        else if(Status==false)
        {
            //$(this).attr('checked',false);
            var conf=confirm('Unmark It?');
            if(conf==true)
                $(this).prop('checked',false);
            else
                $(this).prop('checked',true);
        }   

    });
});
```